# Android bookmarks on home screen don't refresh page

Tags: android, caching, bookmarks

So I've noticed that there's inconsistent behavior with Android browser bookmarks. Those launched from within the browser will get the latest page from the server. Those launched from a shortcut placed on the home screen will often simply reopen the browser and re-display the cached page. This can be problematic because the cached page may be inconsistent with the server version after updates. e.g user makes changes on bookmarked page A, submits to server, which redirects to page B, showing the changes made. When the user clicks the bookmark on the home screen, the original page A is displayed without the changes. What's the best way around this?

Answer (score 1):

have a ajax poll the server to see what latest version is of the page. if that doesn’t match up witth the internal id refresh the page with a random number added to the url.

Comment: What if the browser won't run window.onload? What if its just redisplaying the page without doing anything?

Comment: Thank you anyway, I think yours is a useful suggestion and I appreciate you sharing it with me. I eventually solved my problem in a different way. I had my pages redirect to the same URL